# Prove $f:\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{x}{||x||}$ is not one to one on any open set in its domain.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Prove $f:\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{x}{||x||}$ is not one to one on any open set in its domain.

Comment I know I need to show that given any open set $U$ containing $x$,there is an $x' \in U$ with $f(x)=f(x')$. I was thinking about trying to prove this by contradiction, but I am not getting anywhere I feel. Assume for each $x \neq x'$, $f(x) \neq f(x')$. then $\frac{x}{||x||}\neq \frac{x'}{||x'||}$ so that $x||x'|| \neq x'||x||$. Then $||x||x'||||\neq||x'||x||||$ by taking the norm of both sides but these expressions are equal. Is this correct?

Edit: I honestly do not see where the open sets part of the problem plays into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x\in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is some $r>0$ such that $\|y-x\|<r\implies y\in U$. Take $y=tx$ with $t\in(0,1)$ such that $\|tx-x\|<r(\iff1-t<\frac r{\|x\|}$). Then $y\in U$ and $f(x)=f(y)$.

Comment: Why does $f(x)=f(y)$ hold from the implication?

Comment: Oh because $\frac{tx}{||tx||}=\frac{x}{||x||}$

Comment: @DanielSchmidt Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Any open set containing $\overrightarrow x$ will also contain $c\overrightarrow x$ for a range of $c$ values inside an $\epsilon-$ball. Every scalar multiple of a vector will have the same unit vector, therefore it is not one to one.